# Case Insensitive search in MySQL with REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to do a search on my MySQL database on thy "name" column, with a regular expression that is case insensitive.

```
Select * from customers where name regexp '.$some_var.';
```

It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What is the resultant SQL query ?

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" isn't really that descriptive, if you look at it closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do something like:

```
$some_var = mb_strtolower($some_var);
"SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE LOWER(`name`) REGEXP '" . $some_var . "'";
OR
"SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE LOWER(`name`) REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', ? , '[[:>:]]')";
```

or whatever your regex uses substitute [[:< / >:]] with what you use.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like

```
$result = $this->db->where('name like binary "'.$some_var.'"', NULL, FALSE)
                   ->get('customers')
                   ->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE LOWER(name) REGEXP '.strtolower($some_var).';
```

Comment: why dont you use like im mysql @user2257655

Comment: "SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE  LOWER(name) LIKE %".strtolower($some_var)."%"